# trying to run a loop in java with below code who gives output a - b c- d but getting error package Sytem does not found?

Tags: java

getting two error when trying to compile programm using commandline

```
error-Shuffle1.java:24 error:package System does not exist
   System.out.print("b c")
   Shuffle1.java:31 error:package System does not exist
   System.out.print("b c")
```

letter in word Sytem is also capital then too getting error

```
     public class Shuffle1
     {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         int x=3;

       while(x > 0){

       if(x > 2){

  System.out.print("a");

  }

    x=x-1;

   System.out.print("-");



   if(x==2){

   Sytem.out.print("b,c");


  }

   if(x==1){

   Sytem.out.print("d");

  x=x-1;

  }


 }



 }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is

```
 System.out.print
```

NOT

```
Sytem.out.print
```

Comment: Your welcome, can happen to anybody ;)

Answer (score 1):

Cause you wrote **Sytem** instead System